# Distribute Flutter/Android library(.aar) to third party android App

Tags: android, flutter

I have created the Flutter module and integrated with another existing android project. And
my requirement is to distribute the **android library** to use in the another third party Android app.

I have checked in the internet and did not get any help. Can any one suggest the approach or provide any documentation available on internet.

Comment: To build aar your module needs to be defines as library https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library then you can build that module and in results you will get an AAR file, depending of your environment you can use maven or share aar.

Comment: Just to confirm.
You have an android library which imports a flutter module? "App-in-app" as the documentation calls it.
and now you want to make that android library available to other apps?

So the 3rd party apps import your android library which actually just uses the flutter module?

If I am correct could you please let me know how you got the android module to import the flutter module as I have the same requirement but cannot seem to setup the android module. I have only been able to import the flutter into an APP.